# Java Applet and Html 5

Tags: java, html, applet

Hi I am trying to embed a java applet in a HTML 5 page. But I keep getting a class not found error.

I have 3 files all part of package applet in larger project. I compile the *.java files, then package up with the following command.

```
jar cfm0  DataUpload.jar manifest *.class
```

manifest file

```
 Manifest-Version: 1.0
 Permissions: all-permissions
 Codebase: *
 Application-Name: DataUpload
```

Sign and place the jar in root dir of the HTML page and call the applet with the following code.

```html
<object type="application/x-java-applet" name="DataUpload" width="500" height="300">
  <param name="name" value="DataUpload" />
  <param name="archive" value="DataUpload.jar" />
  <param name="code" value="DataUpload.applet.DataUpload" />
  <param name="scriptable" value="true" />
  <param name="codebase_lookup" value="false" />
  <param name="mayscript" value="true" />
  <param name="plugindetect" value="1" />
</object>
```

Now I think its a problem with code because I was getting wrong name without the applet.DataUpload section. So I added the DataUpload As the base jar address.However no progress

Any help would be very useful

Answer (score 1):

Change `<param name="code" value="DataUpload.applet.DataUpload" />` to `<param name="code" value="DataUpload" />` and make sure your applet isn't actually in a package. If your code is in a package, then your jar command needs to reflect that (you would need to preserve the folder hierarchy to preserve the package name).

Comment: Unfortunately the applet needs to reference other classes in other packages. So I don't think it would be possible to remove it from a package easily. How do change the jar command to keep the folder hierarchy ?

Comment: Issue the jar command from the folder containing the top level package (for example, `com.foo.MyClass` compiles to `com/foo/MyClass.class` and you jar it from the folder containing `com`; and use `com` instead of `*.class`). See also, [setting an application's entry point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html).

Comment: thanks for your help that fixed it. I had to change all the references of DataUpload to applet.DataUpload and it worked !